# Animation on Convergence of A sequence

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, graphics, animations

I am just started learning beamer. For my presentation I want to make a slide to show a animation for my +2 students. I want to explain the concept of convergence of sequence. [image]

I want to explain it for the the sequence {1/n^2}. I will choose epsilon=1/100.I want to draw Y axis labeled as real line. I want to plot the graph of y=1/x^2 restricting the domain to Natural Number. I want to show the points for n=1(y=1) to n=9(y=1/81) of the graph and want to animate so that points will get projected on corresponding Y axis.(for n=5, graph point is (5,1/25)...it is to be projected to (0,1/25) so on[image])

It would be a great help if someone help me creating the code. I know "geogebra" is a 2d drawing software that would generate the tex code to export it in beamer file. But I don't know how to animate it in terms of overlay specification. I complete help is very very welcome. Also it would be a great help if anyone indicates some resource/link that will help me learning how to create this type of simple animation.

moved from comment:

```
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14} 
\centering 
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[xlabel=$\mathbb{N}$,ylabel=$\frac{1}{n^2}$] 
\addplot [samples at={0,...,10},only marks] {1/x^2)}; 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please post what you've got so far as MWE.

Comment: I am not getting. MWE meaning?

Comment: A minimal working example, e.g. a `pgfplots` plot or something what you've done and tried so far (there are some posts on this site which would at least explain how to do the plot without overlays).

Comment: I dont understand....

Comment: Do you even have a plot? Here's one simple version (without uncover): `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmin=0,xmax=11,xtick={1,...,10},ymode=log,ytick={1,0.25,0.1111,0.0625,0.04,0.0277777,0.0204,0.015625,0.01234,0.01},yticklabel={$\frac{1}{\ticknum^2}$},ymax=1.15,domain=1:10,samples=10,axis y line=left,axis x line=bottom]
    \addplot [only marks,thick] {1/x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}` (I know, wrong y axis, but a starter).

Comment: \pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}

\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xlabel=$\mathbb{N}$,ylabel=$\frac{1}{n^2}$]
\addplot [samples at={0,...,10},only marks] {1/x^2)};
\end{axis}

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Please add a [minimal but working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) of the code you already have for the plot into your question (not into a comment!). This means code starting with `\documentclass` and ending (after some preamble code, `\begin{document}` and some body code) with `\end{document}`.